# Did soldiers and/or athletes of ancient times perform any kind of stretch or warmup exercises?

Tags: ancient-history, war, cultural-history, sports

There are some 'time travel' stories where the protagonist, hailing from a modern age, does stretches and warmup exercises (calisthenics, radio, etc) and the natives have no idea what that is.

There's also this old comic from Gary Larson's [The Far Side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Far_Side) depicting Viking warrior stretching out.

[image]

It begs the question, did they do any sort of warmup or stretching before exercising, training, fighting a war?

When was the first recorded case of the use of these exercises, in any form, in history?

Mostly interested in [ancient-history](/questions/tagged/ancient-history).

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: You may be interested in [How would ancient Greeks have exercised?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/45758/how-would-ancient-greeks-have-exercised).